# Providing message and info text for SFCertificateTrustPanel

Tags: cocoa, https, ssl-certificate

When using a `SFCertificateTrustPanel` to display the result of a `SecTrustRef` object, it defaults to the message:

> A failure occurred during certificate trust verification. Please specify the trust settings for the certificates that need updating.

This seems rather vague and lacking compared to Safari's implementation:

> **Safari can't verify the identity of the website "example.com"**
>
> The certificate for this website is invalid. You might be connecting to a website that is pretending to be "example.com", which could put your confidential information at risk. Would you like to connect to the website anyway?

If you let a `NSURLConnection` or similar fail, the `NSError` contains the following:

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "example.com" which could put your confidential information at risk.";
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Would you like to connect to the server anyway?";
```

---

So I seem to have a few options:

1. Leave the default message in place
2. Generate my own message text
3. Wait for the connection to fail, then construct the panel from the resulting error, and retry the connection should the user choose
4. Something else?

Is there an option 4 available that I've missed? If not, which of 2. and 3. is preferable? I'm worried with 2. that it's easy to generate the wrong message by failing to take into account a particular edge case.

Comment: Have you tried [`OSStatus SecTrustEvaluate(SecTrustRef trust, SecTrustResultType *result)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecTrustEvaluate)? Its `OSStatus` return code provides something about 40+ status codes compared to `SecTrustResultType`s 5 .

Comment: @twil my understanding is this function will only return something other than `errSecSuccess` if the evaluation *process* fails (e.g. due to a lack of internet connection). It doesn't report info about why a given certificate is invalid.